# Dynamic Microphone with XLR Phantom power

Tags: audio, microphone, microphonics

I designed this schematic after viewing the typical phantom power supply circuit. But i am still not sure that the dynamic microphone will work or not. Please take a look and tell me.
[image]

I just connected the dynamic microphone element 2 wires with the pin 2 and pin 3 of XLR cable to use it with the interface even when the phantom power is turned on. And i connected pin 1 to the metal body of the same microphone that is covering the circuit and element.
Will this work perfectly? Or do i need to change something inside it.

Thanks alot.!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you're expecting for an answer. Your microphone is not connected to phantom power. Phantom on pin 1 is a standard. This will have no effect on your microphone. If you're really worried about it, take a lesson from Shure's SM series, and put a transformer between the microphone element and XLR connection.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you have it wired correctly and it will work fine.

It doesn't matter if the mixer has phantom power or not, since both pins 2 and 3 will be at 48 VDC and the capsule will have 0 VDC across it.  It's best to turn off phantom if you can, though, in case of small imbalances and to prevent loud pop noises.

Answer (score 0):

the drawing is wrong for the XLR connector. the numbering the details are ok, but in the layout the 3 (low side signal) should be in the center where the 1 (gnd) is shown. the number on the connector will show this orientation